# How to access a data member of a vector full of derived classes

Tags: c++, factory-method

Here is an abstract class that I wrote:

```
 class Month
   {
    public:
       //factory method
       static Month* choose_month(int choice);  //static function
       virtual void birthstone() = 0;           //virtual function
       virtual void month() = 0;                //virtual function
       virtual ~Month()
       {
           std::cout << "Deleting the virtual destructor" << std::endl;
       };
   };

   Month* Month::choose_month(int choice)
   {
    switch (choice)
    {
       case '1':
           return new January;
           break;
       case '2':
           return new February;
           break;
       //these cases go all the way to December
       default:
           break;
       }
    }
```

Then I create twelve derived classes, one for each month of the year. I will include only two of said classes for simplicity:

```
class January : public Month
{
public:
    void birthstone()
    {
        std::cout << "Garnet" << std::endl;
    }

    void month()
    {
        std::cout << "January" << std::endl;
    }

    //destructor
    ~January()
    {
        std::cout << "Deleting the object" << std::endl;
    }
};

class February : public Month
{
public:
    void birthstone()
    {
        std::cout << "Amethyst" << std::endl;
    }

    void month()
    {
        std::cout << "February" << std::endl;
    }

    //destructor
    ~February()
    {
        std::cout << "Deleting the object" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

In my main function I use a random number generator to the select a derived class, so that I can access the data in its member functions:

```
std::vector<Month*> stone;

    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0))); // Seed the random generator

    //for-loop 
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        stone.push_back(Month::choose_month(random(12)));
    }
```

The problem happens when I try to access a member function of any class stored in my vector. I keep getting an access violation error:

```
//displaying the elements inside the container
    for (std::vector<Month*>::iterator iter = stone.begin(); iter != stone.end(); iter++)
    {
        (*iter)->birthstone();
    }
```

I really can't see where the error is, and wonder if someone could please point out whats going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Your `choose_month` function has undefined behaviour because it has non-void return type and doesn't have a `return` statement on every path.

Comment: you have trivial errors which would be caught by the compiler if you crank up the warning level.

Comment: You are switching over characters, not integers.

Comment: Take a break for a few minutes to contemplate the difference between the digit (character) `'1'` and the number `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`case '1'` doesn't do what you expect. `'1'` is not `1`, it's a **char** with integal value `49` (ASCII code). But `random(12)` will return an **int** between `0` and `11`. It means for the `switch` statement in `Month::choose_month()`, the `default` case will always be executed.

Change the `case` statements to `case 1:` and `case 2:` and so on. (Might should from `case 0:` to `case 11:`?) If you expect it to be a `char`, change the parameter's type and change the code calling it too.

And the `default` statement doesn't return anything. You should confirm to return some valid value for this case, or reconsider the design about it (adding asserts or throwing exception for this case, or eliminate the case).

BTW: `random` is not C++ standard facilities. You might use [`std::rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) or [C++11's random number generation facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).